# How to make these boxes in pure html and css?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering what's the technique to make corners like these in the containers. https://modusgames.com/cris-tales/it/#

In the css of this website they're called .green-corners:before and :after, i'm confused.

Comment: If you make a research you will find a lot of tutorials about :after and :before.

Answer (score 1):

They used ::after and ::before and placed them at the corner of their containers here's the code.
**Note:** That shape is not part of the code its just a .png
here it is:
https://modusgames.com/cris-tales/wp-content/themes/cristales-child/images/green-corner.png
You use absolute to move it everywhere of the page and apply position: relative to the parent of your absolute then use width and height to make your img as long as you want and use top/left/right/bottom to change the img location, thats the whole tech you said.

```
.green-corners:before {
        content: "";
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: url(images/green-corner.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

They're using css `pseudo` selectors `:after` and `:before` as decorative elements with image and positioning them. Here is a basic example of doing the same :

Just substitue other images as well. I've just added one as an example

```css
.box{
  width: 300px;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  background: skyblue;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.box:after,.box:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background:orange;
}
.box:before{
  background: url("https://modusgames.com/cris-tales/wp-content/themes/cristales-child/images/green-corner.png") center center no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
.box:after{
  left:auto;
  right:0;
}

.corners{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
.corners:after,.corners:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background:orange;
}
.corners:after{
  left:auto;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <div class="corners">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps !